# .replace() not working. Giving error .replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I've written a javascript function to convert time in 12hrs format

```
function formatDate(nwdate) {
    var d = new Date(nwdate);
    var hh = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var dd = "AM";
    var h = hh;
    if (h >= 12) {
        h = hh-12;
        dd = "PM";
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    }
    m = m<10?"0"+m:m;

    s = s<10?"0"+s:s;


    var pattern = new RegExp("0?"+hh+":"+m+":"+s);

    var replacement = h+":"+m;
    replacement += " "+dd;
    return nwdate.replace(pattern,replacement);
}
```

It gives an error that .replace is not a function. Why is that ?

Comment: I recommend moment.js or similar. But really, *why* is there a regex/replace involved at all? The time has (presumably) already been extracted from the newdate vale.

Comment: @ coder: What is `nwdate`? Clearly that's the issue. It would appear to be something that doesn't have a `replace` function (e.g., not a JavaScript string). That's ***really basic*** information for this question, really shouldn't have to be asking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the object `nwdate` is not a string. As a hack you might try this:

```
(""+nwdate).replace(pattern, replacement);
```

However this is very dependend on the system of the user.